# How to install clang 3.1 using macports? (OSX, snow leopard)

Tags: c++, macos, compiler-construction, clang, macports

I'd like to install the latest clang (3.1) compiler using macports (I use emacs rather than xcode, and the version of clang that comes with xcode is older anyway). macports seems to have the latest versions of gcc, but when I enter "port list clang" the only version that shows up is 2.9. I use the C++11 features, so I want to use the latest version.

I'm running snow leopard on an MBP.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Clang has several different versions available on MacPorts:

```
$ port search clang

clang @2.9 (lang)
    C, C++, Objective C and Objective C++ compiler

clang-2.9 @2.9 (lang)
    C, C++, Objective C and Objective C++ compiler

clang-3.0 @3.0 (lang)
    C, C++, Objective C and Objective C++ compiler

clang-3.1 @3.1-r154872 (lang)
    C, C++, Objective C and Objective C++ compiler

clang-devel @3.0 (lang)
    C, C++, Objective C and Objective C++ compiler

clang_select @0.1 (sysutils)
    common files for selecting default clang version

Found 6 ports.
```

So if you just install the `clang` port, it'll install version 2.9.  If you want 3.1, install the `clang-3.1` port.  You can also install `clang_select`, which is a utility that allows you to easily switch between multiple installations of Clang; without it, you have to manually specify the version of the Clang binary you want each time.

Comment: Thanks. I guess I was confused because "list" shows all the different versions of gcc, but not of clang.

Comment: @BarnabasSzabolcs: Apparently it's secretly a subcommand of `port`—you choose a version of Clang to run with the command `port select --set clang <version>` (and you can list the available versions with `port select --show clang`).

Comment: Maybe because I already had the Apple Developer Tools installed, but after `port install clang-3.3`, the command `port select --show clang` reports 'none'. So it seems `sudo port select --set clang <version>` is always required to activate the macports install.

Comment: The `port select --list clang` command is very important to run to obtain the available version strings to choose from.  It has not seemed to be the obvious choices.  Please run this command to know what the possible version string values are prior to running the `sudo port select --set clang <version>` command.  For the 3.3 Clang, the <version> value is: `mp-clang-3.3`.

Answer (score 1):

Just specify the version number:
`port list clang-3.1`

Worked fine for me. I'm on Lion, but I don't see why that would make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Since the macports repository appears to not have the latest clang, I suggest [building clang from source](http://clang.llvm.org/get_started.html) and then proceeding to [make a new macports package](http://guide.macports.org/#development).