# OSX install multiple version of Clang

Tags: macos, clang

I know that if I install Xcode i would get clang installed bundled with the Xcode.

I want to know if I can install multiple versions of clang(other than the one bundled together with Xcode) on my mac and how?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are many ways you can install another version of Clang. The most straightforward way would be to use **[`MacPorts`](https://www.macports.org/ports.php?by=name&substr=clang)** (Homebrew might be an option also, although I'm not sure). You could compile, build, and install it yourself, however, I would recommend going with the first suggestion as it will not interfere with any of the native system files and you can easily uninstall it if you want.

Comment: Have you actually tried this? clang 9.0.0 doesn't play nice with CUDA 9 as I write this and I don't want to downgrade clang.

Comment: @wcochran: Yes, if you want to know how it works take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10368672